# CruiseControl.NET showing type or namespace error when trying to build NUnit test project

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get CC.net to build and run my NUnit tests (CC.NET is on a separate machine).

However when it hits the `MyProject.Tests.csprog` it bails with the exception:

> The type or namespace 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

The tests build and run perfectly fine in Visual Studio on my local machine.

How do I resolve this build error?

I have NUnit installed on the CC.NET machine. I also have read a number of CC.net/NUnit instructions, but they all refer to including the `MyProject.Tests.dll`, but this DLL does not get generated (build fails with the above error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not have a `ReferencePath` in my `<buildArgs>` element.

```
<buildArgs>/noconsolelogger 
    /v:quiet 
    ...snip...
    /p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\framework"
</buildArgs>
```

Big thanks to Matteo for this blog post https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/category/cruisecontrolnet/